# Get variable value from one JS function to another

Tags: javascript

In my page I get user fb_id in one of function `function1()` when user perform login action.

Later when user click on some button another function call takes place which calls `function2()`. I want to fetch value of `fb_id` in `function2()`. 
How can i do it?

structure is like below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script> 
function fuction2()
{
// some process
var id = fb_it; // Getting fb_it from function1()
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function function1()
{
    var fb_it='xyz';
}
</script>

<button type="submit" onclick="function2()"> GetID </button>
</body>
```

Is it possible or not? If yes then how?

Comment: note that you can't declare a variable with `int fb_it='xyz';`. Use the `var` keyword.

Comment: @dystroy: Yes, it was typo

Answer (score 3):

No you can't directly access a local variable from an external scope.

What you can do is to store the variable externally :

```
function fuction2() {
    var id = fb_it; // Getting fb_it from function1()
}
var fb_it;
function function1() {
    fb_it='xyz';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not knowing global var declaration concept in JS

Answer (score 1):

why don’t you use global variables?

```
<script>
var x = 0;
function(){
x = 7;
}
function(){
x= 8;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function function1()
{
    var fb_it='xyz';
return fb_it;
}

function fuction2()
{
// some process
var id = function1(); // Getting fb_it from function1()
}
```